# How does eq? in Racket work with symbols and number?

Tags: racket

Racket document told me “`eq?` return `#t` if `v1` and `v2` refer to the same object”, but two `fixnums` that are `=` are also the same according to `eq?`, `=` “returns `#t` if all of the arguments are numerically equal”. I can't find any message about “numbers” and “symbols”, but in the example I found :

```lisp
> (eq? 'yes 'yes)
#t
```

This is contradictory to the above, because it was never mentioned above that `symbol` was special, so `'yes` and `'yes` are not the same.

This one makes me even more confused :

```lisp
> (eq? (expt 2 100) (expt 2 100))
#f
> (eq? (* 6 7) 42)
#t
```

if numbers are tested numerically, then `(eq? (expt 2 100) (expt 2 100))` should return `#t`, otherwise, numbers are tested by refer, then `(eq? (* 6 7) 42)` should return `#f`, so I guess both of the above situations are not right...

Why?!

Answer (score 5):

```
(expt 2 100)
```

is too big to be a `fixnum`. Let's try to evaluate:

```
(expt 2 100)  ; => 1267650600228229401496703205376
(fixnum? (expt 2 100)) ; => #f
(expt 2 10) ; => 1024
(fixnum? (expt 2 100)) ; => #t
```

This is because large numbers are allocated in several memory cells (think of them as a list of groups of digits).

On the other hand, each symbol, when read, is “internalized”. This means that the first time it is read, a new symbol value is created for it. Subsequently, when it is read again, the system checks if a symbol with that name is already present, and in this case the old symbol value is returned, without creating any new object in memory. So:

```
(eq 'yes 'yes) ; => #t
```

since what are apparently two different symbols with the same name are in effect the same object in memory.

Comment: Thank you, I probably understand, but how can I check if a data type is “internalized”? Does it simply depend on whether it is allocated in several memory cells?

Answer (score 4):

This is to give additional information in addition to @Renzo's answer

> how can I check if a data type is “internalized”

The answer is that it's complicated.

One factor is the [reader](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html?q=intern#%28tech._interned%29):

> Symbols, keywords, strings, byte strings, regexps, characters, and numbers produced by the reader in `read-syntax` mode are *interned*, which means that such values in the result of `read-syntax` are always `eq?` when they are `equal?` (whether from the same call or different calls to `read-syntax`). Symbols and keywords are interned in both `read` and `read-syntax` mode. Sending an interned value across a place channel does not necessarily produce an interned value at the receiving place. See also `datum-intern-literal` and `datum->syntax`.

So `(eq? (expt 2 100) (expt 2 100))` returns `#f` because `(expt 2 100)` is needed to be computed at runtime. On the other hand, `(eq? 1267650600228229401496703205376 1267650600228229401496703205376)` returns `#t` because the value is apparent at reading time, allowing Racket to intern the number.

Another factor is datatypes. For instance, a fixnum is always interned even if the value is not apparent at reading time, according to https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/numbers.html

> Two fixnums that are `=` are also the same according to `eq?`. Otherwise, the result of `eq?` applied to two numbers is undefined

That means `(eq? (+ 1 2) 3)` is guaranteed to be `#t`.

A symbol is normally interned, but it's possible to make it [uninterned](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/symbols.html?q=gensym#%28tech._uninterned%29) via `string->uninterned-symbol` and `gensym`.

> A symbol is like an immutable string, but symbols are normally interned, so that two symbols with the same character content are normally eq?.
>
> The two procedures string->uninterned-symbol and gensym generate uninterned symbols, i.e., symbols that are not eq?, eqv?, or equal? to any other symbol, although they may print the same as other symbols.

So:

```
> (eq? (string->symbol "ab") (string->symbol (string-append "a" "b")))
#t
> (eq? (string->uninterned-symbol "ab") (string->uninterned-symbol "ab"))
#f
```